# Displaying the name related to the highest number in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I am blanking out and cannot think of how to get the name of the person with highest grade in the array to display. This is the code I have, it all works besides displaying the name of the highest grade, it crashes when it gets to that part.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

const int STUDENTS = 5;
string studentGrade[STUDENTS] = { "Amanda Baynes", "Victor Hughes", "Scott Collins", "Lori Macbeth ", "Manny Lopez  " };
int grades[STUDENTS], count, highest;
highest = grades[0];

for (count = 0; count < STUDENTS; count++)
{
    cout << "Enter score for student " << (studentGrade[count]) << ": ";
    cin >> grades[count];

}

cout << endl;

for (count = 0; count < STUDENTS; count++)
{
    for (count = 0; count < STUDENTS; count++)
        cout << studentGrade[count] << setw(10) << right << grades[count] << endl;
}

for (count = 0; count < STUDENTS; count++)
{
    if (grades[count] > highest)
        highest = grades[count];
    studentGrade[count] = highest;
}
cout << "The highest score " << highest << " is obtained by " << studentGrade[count] << endl;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: `studentGrade[count] = highest;` This shouldn't compile. What do you believe you need this for, anyway? What you do need is an extra variable that remembers the value of `count` at which `highest` grade was achieved.

Comment: Actually, it does compile. There is an `operator=(char)` overload, which is what this ends up calling.

Comment: You should just keep a separate variable to keep track of the student's name with the highest grade. This code has a segmentation fault because he is running off the end of his studentGrade array at the last cout.

Answer (score 3):

```
studentGrade[count] = highest;
```

If you tried to [explain this line of code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), your rubber duck would ask you a question. Given that:

1) This line gets executed for every iteration of the loop, it is not inside the immediately-preceding `if` statement.

2) `studentGrade` is an array of student names,

3) `highest` is the highest score to date.

Your rubber duck will want you to explain why you are attempting to replace the name of each student with the highest score encountered, to date. Can you answer that question?

Besides the fact that this is the wrong way to do it, in the first place, it doesn't even make sense.

You don't want to replace every student's name with anything. You just want to know which student has the highest score. All this code is doing is finding the highest score, but it is not keeping track of which student has it.

```
highest = grades[0];
```

This starts the ball rolling by assuming that student #0 has the highest score. This is a very reasonable, and logical starting point. But you also have to remember that it is student #0 with the highest score. So you also have to keep track of it:

```
int highest_student=0;
```

Now, when you search for the highest score, in addition to recording the highest score, you have to record which student has the highest score:

```
for (count = 0; count < STUDENTS; count++)
{
    if (grades[count] > highest)
    {
        highest = grades[count];
        highest_student = count;
    }
}
```

And now, at the conclusion, the student with the highest score will be student `#highest_student`.

And your rubber duck won't ask you uncomfortable questions (like what the heck would you want to replace the names of all students) any more.

Answer (score 1):

You are running off the end of your array with this line

```
cout << "The highest score " << highest << " is obtained by " << studentGrade[count] << endl;
```

By the time it reaches this line, `count` is greater than the length of your `studentGrade` array.

The easiest way to fix your problem is to just have a separate variable to keep track of the name associated with the highest grade. Then print this instead of `studentGrade[count]` (not sure what you are even trying to do here).

Also initializing this variable `highest = grades[0];` like so will result in undefined behaviour (what was the thought process here?) because `grades` is uninitialized. You should set it to some concrete value, like `0`.

Answer (score 0):

First, notice that you take the value of `grades[0]` in the variable called **highest** before taking the input of grades into the array which might prove to be fallible in some cases.

Now, consider the **if statement**

```
if (grades[count] > highest)
    highest = grades[count];
studentGrade[count] = highest; //this is a syntax error
                              //since base type of the array
                             //gradeStudent is String and that of
                            //variable highest is int
```

You do actually get the highest grade in the variable **highest** but the statement `studentGrade[count] = highest` firstly is syntactically incorrect and secondly, even if it was syntactically correct, gets executed every time in the loop (since it is outside the if statement: you probably forgot to place it within the braces of the if statement) thereby messing (tries to mess) with the values of **grades** array.

I recommend using this **logic**: Having the names and grades of the students in the respective arrays in order, fetch the `index` of the highest value (i.e., highest grade) in the **grades** array, i.e., the position in the array at which the highest grade lies. The same will be the index of the student getting the highest grade.

Consider the code below.

```
/* get the input of grades in grades array */
highest = 0; //assuming that highest grade lies at index 0
for(count = 0; count < STUDENTS; count++){
    if(grades[count] > grades[highest])
        highest = count;
}
cout << "The student with the max grade is " << studentGrade[highest];
```

Hope this solves your problem.